# Logical comparison of Java synchronized keyword and Spring @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, spring, transactions

At one of presentations about Spring/Hibernate transactions I brought up an opinion that `synchronized` keyword on a method and `@Transactional` logically have many similarities. Sure enough they are totally different beasts but yet they both applied as aspects to the method and both control access to some resources via some kind of shared monitor (record in db, for example).

There were couple of people in the crowd who immediately opposed and claimed that my comparison is fatally wrong. I don't remember specific arguments but I can see some point here as well. For example, `synchronized` works for the entire method from the beginning and transaction will only have effect when statement to access DB is reached. Plus `synchronized` does not offer any read/write locking pattern.

So the question is, is my comparison totally wrong and I should never ever use it, or, with proper wording, would it make sense to present it to experienced engineers who know well how `synchronized` works but yet trying to learn about AOP transactions? What this wording should be?

---

A bit of update.

Apparently my question sounded like comparing DB transactions vs entering `synchronized` method in Java. That's not the case. My idea is more about comparing similarities in semantics of `@Transactional` and `synchronized`.

One of the reason I brought it up also was to illustrate propagation behavior. For example, if `@Transactional` is PROPAGATION_REQUIRED it will have many similarities to entering `synchronized` block. For transaction: if transaction is present we just continue using it and if not, we will create one. For `synchronized`, if we already have monitor we proceed with it and if not we will attempt to acquire it. Of course for `@Transactional` we are not going to lock on method boundary.

Comment: They're totally different beasts, and I think keeping using this comparison won't bring anything but confusion to your audience.

Comment: just to point the extremely obvious: transactions can commit and rollback, synchronization ensures only exclusive access. There is nothing in common, as transactions are not even required to lock objects.

Comment: Note that I am not comparing DB transactions vs JVM monitor manipulations but merely similarities in semantics of `synchronized` and `@Transactional`

Comment: *For synchronized, if we already have monitor we proceed with it and if not we will attempt to acquire it.* actually it does increase the acquired count, thus you should consider it Int, no boolean like propagation types. In that case the lock is released when the count reaches zero unlike the transaction propagation which is either committed or rolled back defined by the container. Side note is, you should avoid sync. on whole methods b/c most of the time not the entire code path should be locked.

Answer (score 5):

If we look at `@Transactional` as denoting a method that locks a database resource (because it is used in the transaction) - then the comparison makes some sense.

However this is all they have in common. synchronized is defined on an object monitor (and protects only it), which is known at the time of usage of the keyword, while a transaction may lock multiple resources (that are not known when the transaction starts), or may not lock any resources at all (optimistic locking, read-only transactions).

So ultimately - don't use that comparison, there are a lot more things that they differ in than they have in common.

Answer (score 4):

The concepts embodied in `@Transactional` annotation are much more complex than those embodied in `synchronized` keyword. I agree with JB Nizet's comment that your comparison is counter-intuitive and would confuse your audience.

With Java synchronization, you always know exactly what is being locked, from which point in the code and to which point. You have built-in the concept of threads and a queue of threads competing for the same resource. Also, you are in effect locking code, not locking data. It may seem like a nuance, but the difference could be substantial.

With @Transactional, first you have the issue of transactions demarcation. You don't know exactly when a transaction begins, since you might reach this method after already having opened a transaction. For the same reason, you don't know if the transaction will end when you exit the method.

Secondly, transaction isolation semantics are much more complex then just synchronization (read-only, read-write, etc.). Many times isolation answers a concern about data integrity, and not intrinsically a concern about queuing access to a resource. Sometimes just one record is locked, sometimes a whole table (again, this is data, not code). Further more, transactions can be rolled-back, a concept that is important for data integrity and doesn't exist with `synchronized`.

Comment: `You don't know exactly when a transaction begins, since you might reach this method after already having opened a transaction.` It's not very different with `synchronized`, you can enter `synchronized` method owning monitor already, so you don't know if method boundaries will grab/release monitor.

Comment: @Alex, you are correct in principle, but in practice, in terms of code readability, it is not the same. I think that when using nested synchronization it is usually fairly obvious to the reader (and also typically in the same class). Transactions demarcation is, in my opinion, less obvious when you just look at the methods.