# Spring Data JPA: Find object after update is not always the updated object

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

We notice in our application that the find-method does not always return the latest object.

We have a repostiory like this (simplified):

```
public interface ObjRepo extends JpaRepository<Obj, Integer> {
  @Secured({})
  @RestResource(exported = false)
  Obj findObjByObjToken(String ObjToken);
}
```

Simplified, we have a webservice doing something like this:

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();

private ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest request) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        String token = request.getParameter("token");
        Obj obj = objRepo.findObjByObjToken(token);
        obj.changeStuff();
        objRepo.save(obj);
        return ...;
    }
}
```

The webservice is called multiple times at the same time; because of the synchronized lock, all calls will be handled serial.

I would expect the findObjByObjToken always to return the updated value, but very often it returns the old version.
We did some tests, and the break-off point seems to be around 600 ms.

How can we make sure the 'find' always returns the updated version?

(edit; we use Spring 1.3.3.RELEASE)

Comment: what is your transaction scope? what are you returning? when you say updated you mean from the previouse request?

Comment: We did not set any transaction scope, I actually don't know what the default is. We return a modelandview with a success (or fail) message for the user. Yes, I mean theupdate from the  previous call.

Comment: can you share the full controller?

Comment: What part you specifically want to see? I don't think posting a few thousand lines of code will help solving this issue; as far as I know all other code is not related to this problem... If it's necessary I will have to write a small test case, to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: if your controller is few thousand lines of code then it needs refactoring, I want to see if there are any changes on the lock

Comment: I'm not sure.. What if you add `@Transactional` annotation to `ObjRepo` interface, and add `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` to  `findObjByObjToken` method?

Comment: @AmerQarabsa: the lock is not changed at all.

Comment: @Cepr0: Thanks, I will try it (testing is a bit difficult, it will take a while).

Comment: The main idea is to separate 'write' and 'read' methods to independent transactions. In general, I would try to implement a service between the repository and the controller, where will set up transactions...

Comment: @DennisvanBeek could you try something for me please, add Thread.sleep(1000) before the synchronized block

Comment: Drop the synchronised and use @Transactional annotation
or try flush() to flush all pending changes to the database. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479283/logical-comparison-of-java-synchronized-keyword-and-spring-transactional-annota

Comment: Put the logic inside a service, which is called from your controller. Make the service `@Transactional`. Currently you have 2 transactions instead of a single one. Also using `synchronized` is a bad idea, unless you don't really care for performance and end-user experience of course.